# PHP merge arrays and send through wp_insert_post()

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to merge the following arrays.

**I want this result:**

```
foreach( $datas as $data ) {
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title['title_value'],
        'post_status'   => 'pending',
        'post_type'     => $type['type_value'],
        'post_author'   => $author['author_value'],
    );
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```

**My data:**

```
$title  = title1,title2,,title4,title5      // 5 datas separated with coma
$type   = type1,type2,type3,type4,,     // 5 datas separated with coma
$author = ,author2,author3,author4,author5  // 5 datas separated with coma
```

**What I have done:**

```
$datas = array(
    'title'     => explode( ",", $title ),
    'type'      => explode( ",", $type ),
    'author'    => explode( ",", $author ),
);

foreach( $datas as $data ) {
   // foreach( $data as $d ) {

   // }
}
```

**Does anybody know how to do this?**
**Hope you can understand the question. Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your all data(title,type and author) have same data count you can use this way

```html
$title_array = explode(',', $title);
$type_array = explode(',', $type);
$author_array = explode(',', $author);
if (count($title_array) > 0)
{
   foreach ($title_array as $title_index => $title_value)
   {
      $my_post = array(
          'post_title' => $title_value,
          'post_status' => 'pending',
          'post_type' => $type_array[$title_index],
          'post_author' => $author_array[$title_index],
      );
      wp_insert_post($my_post);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Working fine.